# Using the Dynamic Router EIP with the Load Balancer EIP

Tags: apache-camel, load-balancing, enterprise-integration

I want to redirect the message in the DynamicRouterBean depending on where it was sent to by the load balancer EIP. I was trying to access the previous endpoint inside DynamicRouterBean using @Header(Exchange.SLIP_ENDPOINT) but that's being set to null (Why?). Even when i get the Exchange (in the DynamicRouterBean), the fromEndPoint is direct://my-lb (but expected it to be either direct://my-lb-a or direct://my-lb-b??).

I later used the CamelHistory to see which endpoints the message had been but still have the question. Isn't the previous end point (or fromEndPoint, or Exchange.SLIP_ENDPOINT) one of the load balancer end points?

```
from("direct://my-lb")
    .loadBalance().roundRobin()
        .to("direct://my-lb-a")
        .to("direct://my-lb-b")
    .end()
.dynamicRouter(method(DynamicRouterBean.class, "slip"));
```

Comment: Yes there is a TO_ENDPOINT - just take a closer look at what data you have on the exchange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me, Thanks Claus Ibsen. Would be great if you could answer instead of commenting so i can accept your answers :)

```
public String slip(String body, @Header(Exchange.TO_ENDPOINT) String toEndPoint) {
...
}
```